# data validation

Tags: java

I am writing a loan calculate with data validation. My maximum loan amount is 1,000,000 and I am using the method below to validate. When I enter 1,000,000 into the program it comes back with my error method. I thought (d >= max) would allow me to go up to and including my max. Can anyone see a problem with this method or is it possible I should be looking elsewhere in my code for a problem.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, double min, double max)
{
    double d = 0.0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {

        d = getDouble (sc, prompt);
        if (d <= min)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + "." );
        }
        else if (d >= max)
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max + "." );
        }

        else
            isValid = true;
    }
    return d;
```

//Get input from user
            System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
            double loanAmount = getDoubleWithinRange (sc,
                "Enter loan amount:           ",0, 1000000);
            double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange (sc,
                "Enter yearly interest rate:  " , 0, 20);
            int years = getIntWithinRange (sc,
                "Enter number of years:       ",0,100);

Comment: Show some input and output (ideally copy/paste from console window); also show the code that calls this method and the values being passed in.

Comment: Welcome to the loan calculator

DATA ENTRY
Enter loan amount:           1000000
Error! Number must be less than 1000000.0.
Enter loan amount:

Comment: sorry I dont know how to post the code other than in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saying if the amount is greater than **or equal** to one million cause an error. you want to say if it is greater than show an error

Comment: ok I took the = sign out and now it is (d > max) and it still says number needs to be less than a million

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if (d>max)`, since you want up to 1,000,000 (and 1,000,000 can be included).